# Why do I get Abort (core dumped)

Tags: c, free

I have this piece of code but I get Abort(core dumped). When I comment the Destroy line everything is okay so I suppose that the mistake is there. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxelem 100
#define NIL -1

typedef int BHItem;

struct node {
        BHItem data;
        int priority;
};

typedef struct node *BHNode;

BHNode BHCreate()               //This function creates an empty heap
{
        BHNode heap;
        int i;
        heap=malloc(maxelem*sizeof(struct node));
        for (i=0; i<maxelem; i++) {
                heap[i].data=NIL;
                heap[i].priority=NIL;
        }
}

void BHDestroy(BHNode heap)             //This function destroys a heap
{
        free(heap);
}

int main()
{
        BHNode heap;
        heap=BHCreate();
        BHDestroy(heap);        //Destroy the heap
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to `return heap` from `BHCrreate()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `BHCreate` is missing a `return heap;` as a final statement. It should look like this:

```
BHNode BHCreate()
{
        BHNode heap;
        int i;
        heap=malloc(maxelem*sizeof(struct node));
        for (i=0; i<maxelem; i++) {
                heap[i].data=NIL;
                heap[i].priority=NIL;
        }

        return heap;
}
```

You should turn on compiler warnings to discover such things:

```
$ gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra
main.c: In function ‘BHCreate’:
main.c:26:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```